# Simple reduction (NP completeness)

Tags: shortest-path, np-complete, reduction

I'm looking for a means to prove that the bicriteria shortest path problem is np complete.
That is, given a graph with lengths and weights, I need to know if a there exists a path in the graph from s to t with total length <= L and weight <= W.

I know that i must take an NP complete problem and reduce it to this one. We have at our disposal the following problems to choose from: 3-SAT, independent set, vertex cover, hamiltonian cycle, and 3-dimensional matching.

Any ideas on which may be viable?

thanks

Comment: You may want to stop by your professor's office hours. 1-1 time with computer science phds is an invaluable part of your education.  You should take advantage of it while you can.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have my copy of Garey and Johnson here, and don't remember what some of those problems are.  If you'd edit your question to give quick definitions, it might help people find them.  (Example:  3-SAT:  Given a set of boolean variables, and a set of clauses that OR together three variables, some of which may be negated, can you assign truth values to the variables such that all the clauses are true?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try Google?  3rd hit is:

http://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/ieejeiss/128/3/128_416/_article

The article is pay-per-view, but the Google cache supplies the important bit upfront:

"Unfortunately, the multiobjective case ( including the bicriteria case) is NP-complete(3).

and the reference points to:

(3) M. Garey and D. Johnson : Computers, and Intractability : A Guide to the theory of NP-Completeness, New York: Freeman (1979)

which is the standard reference for questions of this form.

So ... have you looked at Garey and Johnson?  I don't have a copy here to check, but it was my go-to when I did comps.

Comment: Thing is, what Garey and Johnson is really useful for in this is a massive compendium of NP-complete problems.  Frequently your problem will be in there (I'd assume the professor would have checked this), and otherwise it's a great source of problems to try to reduce to what you've got.

In this case, the student gets five problems to choose from, which is already a lot easier to handle than the hundreds (literally) in G&J.

Comment: Sometimes G&J will help with a problem like this by suggesting a derivation chain ... either directly to one of the more familiar problems, or else through some intermediate problem that suggests a strategy for constructing a direct proof.